# Why is my ComboBox SelectedItem null?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, mvvm-light

I have a WPF/MVVM (using MVVM-Light) app setup with a ComboBox that is inside a DataTemplate. The XAML of the ComboBox looks like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbTeachers" 
          Grid.Column="1" 
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBox}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Teachers}" 
          Grid.Row="3" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedValuePath="Id" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTeacher}">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TeacherSelectedCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cbTeachers}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

The **Teachers** property for the ItemsSource is a type called ObservableRangeCollection and is based on the code found here: http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/16/have-worker-thread-update-observablecollection-that-is-bound-to-a.aspx, but it's very similar to a standard ObservableCollection. The **SelectedTeacher** property is set when another property is set and the code looks very similiar to this:

```
this.SelectedTeacher = (from t in this.Teachers where t.Id == this.DataItem.Teacher.Id select t).Single();
```

The problem I am running into, which makes zero sense to me, is SelectedTeacher is getting reset to null once I set it. I can step through the debugger and see SelectedTeacher has a value and when I put a breakpoint on the setter for the property it definitely has the value. But then that property gets hit again with a null value. I checked the call stack and it showed the only preceeding line as being External Code (which makes sense since I only set that property in one place and it only gets hit once, as expected). Expanding the External Code option in the call stack window shows the typical WPF call stack of maybe 40 methods so it's definitely internal to WPF and not something I am doing to make it reset. In fact, when I remove the SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTeacher}" the setter for that property doesn't get called a second time (thus it retains its value), but of course the ComboBox doesn't show the selected item either. I tried implementing a SelectedIndex option in my viewmodel but that didn't work either. The ComboBox just won't select the item. I can change the selected item in the ComboBox just fine, but the initial setting won't take.

Any ideas? Based on everything I've searched it might be related to me using a DataTemplate, but I have to because that template is part of a parent ContentTemplateSelector implementation.

As a side note, I have multiple properties that bind to controls in this DataTemplate and this is the only one that doesn't work. The others work perfectly. I have also tried the ComboBox with and without the "IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" flag and it made no difference.

Comment: why you bind to SelectedItem and also to SelectionChanged?

Comment: The goal is setting the existing value (the user is in edit mode) and then letting them change the value should they choose. SelectionChanged's command implementation just sets SelectedTeacher equal to the value they selected. It's pretty basic actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried to remove to EventTrigger stuff and just to use

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTeacher, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

with Mode=TwoWay?

its not clear to me what you want to achieve with your EventTrigger?

Comment: I tried this and it still sets the SelectedTeacher property a second time with a null value. The goal behind this is setting the initial selected value (because they are editing an existing item) and then using SelectionChanged to update the SelectedTeacher value if they decide to change the value.

Comment: Got it! I removed the command from the ComboBox and changed a couple of other things with the end of the ComboBox's declaration so it looked like this:  DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedTeacher, Mode=TwoWay}". It looks like a combination of removing the command, changing to SelectedValue (not Item) and removing the SelectedValuePath option took care of it. Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: Well, I almost had it with the above but it turns out it was selected *a* value, but not the correct one. When I set "IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" to false it started working as expected. WPF sure does make things confusing sometimes. HTH someone else in the future!